# Only update data in local database from web service if the data is new

Tags: c#, android, web-services, sqlite, asp.net-web-api2

I have coded a C# Web API 2 web service, and am wanting to retrieve this data in an android application that I have coded.

I wish to have a local SQL database on my android device that stores the data from the web service.

Whenever data is to be used in my android application, I wish to check to see if the local database data is the most up to date, and if it isn't, then I wish to retrieve the latest data from the web service.

I am thinking of the following:

1. Each time data is saved into the local database, save an integer value as an update number.
2. Whenever data is required, retrieve the latest update number from the local database, send a request to the web service with this update number, and only return data if the web service data has a newer update number.

Would this work well? Is there a better approach to this problem than my above idea? Are there any disadvantages or errors that could occur?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Would this work well?" : Actually it's about the only easy way to do it.

Comment: Are there more complex ways to achieve the desired result that you recommend?

Comment: I would be more inclined to save a DateTime of the last update, pass this back to the web service and allow the web service to retrieve records that have been updated since this datetime.

Comment: @user3736648 : Why do you want something more complicated? As long as your app maintains the last known version and the web server reliably updates its version number when anything changes then things will work. As BenjaminPaul points out, a timestamp can be used instead of a version number but it depends on if you intend to download the complete database data or just incrementally download changes - that gets quite a bit more complex especially if there are data deletions and / or changes to database schema.

Comment: I only intend to download incrementally download changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly same thing with my synchronization algorithm. It's like this. 
My web service methods gets datetime parameters, web service sends objects only created or modified after that time.

On the mobile side, I keep synchronization start time, and for the each synchronization, i send previous sync start time. (By the way, I ask date to server just before sync starts)

I dont keep sync end time, because some of the data may be modified after sync started.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing in my sync adapter where user click on sync and it get data from web feeds and store only updated data into sqlite.

refer to `SyncAdapter.java` file of sync adapter sample provided on http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html